# Format the initial value of the ng-model (input type text with datePicker)

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, angular-ngmodel

I have an input type text with a datePicker.

```
<input id="start-date" style="width: 230px;" close-text="Close"
 type="text" ng-model="startDate"  datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"  
ng-required="true"/></div>
```

When the input is showed I must display an initial value for it. The problem is that this value is displayed in this format:

`Wed Jun 15 2016 10:48:49 GMT+0000 (WET)`

it's just after selecting a date from the datePicker that I can see the format that I want (dd-MM-yyyy). To solve this problem I added:

```
$scope.$watch('startDate', function (newValue) {
  $scope.startDate = $filter('date')(newValue, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
});
```

But I get this error: Datepicker directive: "ng-model" value must be a Date object, a number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970 or a string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: in the ng-model? Like this: `ng-model="startDate | date"` ?

Comment: are you using  AngularUI datepicker ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the AngularUI datepicker and your initial value for the ng-Model does not get formatted simply adding the following directive to your project will fix the issue:

```
directive('datepickerPopup', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
      //remove the default formatter from the input directive to prevent conflict
      controller.$formatters.shift();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have already this directive in the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file but I don't have this in it `controller.$formatters.shift();`

Comment: Have I to add it in this file?

Comment: just add a new file as a new directive, just like your controller

Comment: I put the directive into a new file, I named the directive "SdatepickerPopup" (because I have already a directive named "datepickerPopup"), and I added the new directive into my input (I just added it without removing anything from the input) but I still getting the same error even if the date is displayed correctly (like what I have before trying your suggestion).

Comment: please see this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/L9u12BeeBgPC2z0nlrLZ?p=preview

Comment: If still not clear than read this thread https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2659

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to test it like you did and when it works I will tell you. Thank you again!

Comment: Can you please explain me what this line exactly means? `controller.$formatters.shift();`  I understand that the formatter of the datePicker isn't applied to the first ng-model. Is that correct?